# Creating a network using R

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

I need to create an instance of a node using R, but I also need some attributes of the node to exist:

1. how many connections/links the node has (i.e. how many neighbors does it have)
2. what these connections are (for example if the node is 1 and is connected to node 2, it needs to be an attribute)
3. need to set a value to the node (either 0 or 1)

Also, how to use a loop to create more instances of this node, but with different values for the same attributes.

I've spent hours looking for a solution, and tried many packages, but there's always a problem.

Can anybody suggest a solution please and provide a complete example as possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this network? You could probably represent the data structure you describe as a data.frame.

Comment: I want to create a simplex random network consisting of many nodes connected together.

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do with it? What type of analyses do you want to apply?

Comment: I want to know the speed at which something, say information, propagates from one node to another influencing the 0 or 1 attribute, and therefore how long it takes for the majority of the nodes to change from either 0 or 1 to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using something like the `igraph` library may work well here. e.g:

Make a data.frame containing the relationships between nodes

```
node.data <- data.frame(
    one=c("a","a","b"),
    two=c("b","c","c")
  )
```

Make a graph/network from the data

```
g <- graph.data.frame(
  node.data,
  directed=FALSE # make this true if your network has a direction in the links
)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Add values to each vertex (node)

```
g <- set.vertex.attribute(g,"value",value=c(1,0,0))
```

These can then be retrieved as such:

```
get.vertex.attribute(g,"value")
#[1] 1 0 0
```

To adapt this to randomly generating a network, you can make use of the `sample` function.

E.g. using something like...

```
one=sample(letters[1:10],100,replace=TRUE)
```

...inside the `data.frame` call will allow you to randomly generate links. The same could be applied for generating the vertex attributes like...

```
sample(0:1,100,replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: @user3043867: with all that help from thelatemail, please make sure to upvote his answer and accept it by clicking the tick mark on the left.